# Scattering of slow neutrons

Tags: scattering, neutrons

I've here a spectrum which was obtained from the scattering of slow neutrons on uran.
But I'm not sure what I'm actually see there. Can someone explain the "scattering of slow neutrons"?

Edit:

[image]

Best

Comment: Show us the spectrum. Do you mean "Uranium" by "uran"? Also, tell us what exactly you need explained.

Comment: Perhaps a link to the paper or book where you found this would be in order.

Comment: @QuantumMechanics Scattering amplitude depends on angle. What is the angle of scattering? The peaks seem like resonances to me, but you gave us too little information.

Comment: Most spectroscopists would call these spectra "forests" (because all the peaks look like the trunks of many trees), and they imply that the systems you are probing are complicated. Perhaps understanding the method in a simpler system would be useful.

Comment: The picture is from [this paper](http://journals.aps.org/prc/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevC.6.1854). It's a study of the nuclear energy levels of Uranium and Thorium. The picture probably came from the publications by [this group](http://nuclear.fis.ucm.es/wordpress/?page_id=29) on using the method of random matrices to understand excitations of nuclei. I have an idea this is also related to the distribution of zeros of the Zeta function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That particular plot ([source](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevC.6.1854)) seems to be a plot of the number of neutron captures as a function of energy. Each narrow peak in neutron energy corresponds to the energy of an excited state in the Th-233 or U-239 nucleus --- that is, the target nucleus with an extra neutron.

The size of the capture cross section, plus the properties of the decay radiation emitted as the nucleus relaxes to its new ground state, lets you assign a spin and intrinsic parity to each excited state. A useful model of the nuclear interaction would be able to predict some of these excited states; contrariwise, this set of neutron cross sections permits you to model the behavior of Th-232 or U-238 in a bath of warm neutrons, as found in a reactor.